# Parsing XML with lxml and elementtree

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse XML document to return `<input>` nodes that contain a `ref` attribute.  A toy example works but the document itself returns an empty array, when it should show a match.

**toy example**

```
import elementtree.ElementTree
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.XML('<body><input ref="blabla"><label>Cats</label></input><input ref="blabla"><label>Dogs</label></input><input ref="blabla"><label>Birds</label></input></body>')
# I can return the relevant input nodes with:
print len(tree.findall(".//input[@ref]"))
2
```

But working with the following (reduced) file for some reason fails:

**example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <h:head>
    <h:title>A title</h:title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <group ref="blabla">
      <label>Group 1</label>
      <input ref="blabla">
        <label>Field 1</label>
      </input>
    </group>
  </h:body>
</h:html>
```

**script**

```
import elementtree.ElementTree
from lxml import etree
with open ("example.xml", "r") as myfile:
  xml = myfile.read()
tree = etree.XML(xml)
print len(tree.findall(".//input[@ref]"))
0
```

Any idea why this fails, and how to workaround?  I think it may have something to do with the XML header.  Very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: What's the error message? What exactly fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the elements in your entire document are in particular namespaces, so that the un-namespaced `.findall(".//input[@ref]"))` expression doesn't match the `input` element in the document, which is actually a namespaced `input` element, in the `http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms` namespace.

So maybe try this:

```
.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms}input[@ref]")
```

**Updated** after my original answer, to use the xforms namespace instead of the xhtml namespace (as had been noted in another answer).

Comment: Hi sideshowbarker. Sorry still an empty array for me.

Comment: OK, I didn’t actually test it, but will do that right now and see what I get

Comment: Ha ha! `.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms}input[@ref]")` is the ticket :)

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen from your xml , the xml-namespace for non-prefixed elements is - `"http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"` , This is because that is defined as the `xmlns` without any prefix in the parent element `h:html` , only elements prefixed `h:` have the namespace as `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

So you need to use that namespace in your query as well. Example -

```
root.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms}input[@ref]")
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> s = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
... <h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...   <h:head>
...     <h:title>A title</h:title>
...   </h:head>
...   <h:body>
...     <group ref="blabla">
...       <label>Group 1</label>
...       <input ref="blabla">
...         <label>Field 1</label>
...       </input>
...     </group>
...   </h:body>
... </h:html>"""
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.fromstring(s)
>>> root.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}input[@ref]")
>>> root.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms}input[@ref]")
[<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms}input' at 0x02288EA0>]
```